# Django 2.2 - how to express a constraint between two fields

Tags: django, database, constraints

I have a couple of models that look like this:

```
class AlarmStatus(Enum):
    UNDEFINED = "Undefined"
    PENDING = "Pending"
    CUSTOMER_PENDING = "Customer Pending"

    @classmethod
    def choices(cls):
        return tuple((i.name, i.value) for i in cls)


class Alarm(models.Model):
    managed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Managed ?")
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, default=AlarmStatus.UNDEFINED.name, choices=AlarmStatus.choices()
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(managed=False) & Q(status=AlarmStatus.UNDEFINED.name),
                name="if_managed_is_False_status_must_be_UNDEFINED")
               ]
```

I would like to enforce at the db level the following invariant:

**if an alarm `managed` field is False, then its `status` field MUST be "UNDEFINED"**.

I.e. I want to declare illegal the following state/combination:

`managed` == False AND `status` == (PENDING | CUSTOMER_PENDING)

How can I enforce this?

I tried with the above constraint but it is clearly wrong, because it is enforcing that every row `managed` field must be False AND every row `status` must be UNDEFINED.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An [*implication* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) (i.e. *A → B*) can be expressed as *¬A∨B*, so you can represent this as:

```
models.CheckConstraint(
    check=Q(managed=True) | Q(status=AlarmStatus.UNDEFINED.name),
    name="if_managed_is_False_status_must_be_UNDEFINED"
)
```

It thus means that the check is satisfied if `managed` is `True` (since then we do not care about the `status`, or the status should be `UNDEFINED`.

Comment: Brilliant: now if I try to update the status of any unmanaged alarm to any value other than UNDEFINED, I get back an IntegrityError. The only issue is that it still allows me to update a *managed* alarm with status = UNDEFINED...django automatically set the `managed` field back to False but I would like to return an IntegrityError in this case too.

Comment: @pastoreerrante: this might something with the database. What happens if you make an update at the database side?

Comment: `>>> managed_alarm = Alarm.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> managed_alarm.status
'PENDING'
>>> managed_alarm.managed
True
>>> 
>>> 
>>> managed_alarm.status = "UNDEFINED"
>>> 
>>> managed_alarm.save()
>>> 
` trying with django python shell I can reproduce the issue. If I set an unmanaged alarm to any value other than UNDEFINED I get instead the integrity error.